# Why I cannot pass the correct argument to my static function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I found a function for parsing date and time here: https://gist.github.com/jacks205/4a77fb1703632eb9ae79#file-timeago-swift and I've decided to use it in my project. I copied it into a new class and added a `shared instance`:

```
class DateCalculation {
    static let sharedInstance = DateCalculation()

    func timeAgoSinceDate(date:NSDate, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let now = NSDate()
        let earliest = now.earlierDate(date)
        (...)
```

now when I'm using it in another place in the code I'm doing:

```
DateCalculation.timeAgoSinceDate(created_at);
```

and in this case `created_at` is a type of `NSDate`. But I'm getting error:

```
cannot convert value of type NSDate to expected argument type DateCalculation
```

what's the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your call should have the following form:

```
DateCalculation.sharedInstance.timeAgoSinceDate(created_at)
```

You are not calling a static method, you are calling an instance method on a singleton.

Also note that your definition has two parameters and you are calling it with just once parameter (you can also make the second parameter optional by assigning it a default value, e.g `numericDates:Bool = true`)

Another option is to just declare the method as `class`, if you are not using any instance variable:

```
class func timeAgoSinceDate(date:NSDate, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
```

Comment: Thank you! can you just tell me how should I exactly use the 2nd option proposed by you - `class func`? Do I need to declare it inside of my `DateCalculation` class? and if yes - how can I call it from some other place in code?

Comment: @user3766930 Yes, then you will be able to call `DateCalculation.timeAgoSinceDate(...)` directly.